# Fetch/React not redirecting with Node/Express res.redirect()

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, fetch

On my React front-end, I make a fetch() GET call to my Node/Express server. The Node/Express server checks if response has a certain cookie, and if not should redirect it. My code is something like this:

React code

```
componentDidMount(){
      fetch('/example',{redirect: "follow"})
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(res => {
        //do something with response
         }
      })
   }
```

Node/Express:

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    let { token } = req.cookies;

    if(token){
        next();
    }
    else{
        res.redirect(303, '/login');
    }
});

router.get('/example', (req, res) =>{
    //sends a json response back
})
```

It might be important to note that I am using react-router-dom as a browser router, thought I'm not sure what this does to server redirects. I've searched and saw people who said to set redirect to "follow". However, even when setting status to a 3xx and setting redirect to "follow", the page still doesn't redirect properly. Instead, it receives a response with `200 OK status`(which I don't understand how it could have changed, unless Node/Express didn't actually set it to '303'), `redirected: true`, and a response.url pointing to the redirect url, but still stays on the same page. I've made sure that the cookie isn't there, so that's not it. I know I can probably check response.redirected every time and manually set window.location = response.url, but I still don't understand why the redirect did not work. Do I have to set it manually everytime then?

Comment: Setting redirect to `follow` doesn't mean that the browser will be redirected to `Location` as if you were pressing a regular anchor tag on the page, but `fetch` itself will create a new request under the hood to `Location`. If you check the Network tab of your Developer Tools you will see this in action. If you want to change the browser URL, you could set redirect to `manual` instead and check for the redirect yourself and set `window.location.href = "http://example.com/something";` if it was a redirect.

Comment: I'm confused, then why doesn't this redirect? I intend to set it manually in the future as a solution to this problem, but I'm not manually setting here. Why doesn't "follow" work then?

Comment: Have you looked at the Networks tab? Are you sure it's not redirecting? It should get a redirect, redirect automatically, get to the proper URL, and give you that as result of the `fetch`.

Comment: Oh ok, I see what you mean. Fetch does make a get call to the redirected url. Why does it not redirect then? The redirected url is supposed to res.sendFile()

Comment: I can't say for certain, but I think it is redirecting as it should. If you look at the response from the final request the `fetch` does, does it contain the file you send?

Comment: It does. If I click on the response, it's the correct page that I want to redirect to. So fetch is fetching the correct redirect, but just not actually rendering it React for some reason